# How can I extract the JobSeekerID with UserDefaults swift 3

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm trying to fetch the jobSeeker ID from my api using the userDefaults but I'm having a nil as response.

Basically, what I'm doing is:

Creating a helper class as NSObject and saving the token (which is working unlike my userID).

```
class helper: NSObject {

class func restartApp(){
    guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else {return}

    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController : UIViewController

    if getApiToken() == nil {
        //go to auth screen
        viewController = storyBoard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
    } else {
        //go to main screen
        viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profileNavigationController")
    }

    window.rootViewController = viewController

    UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionFlipFromTop, animations: nil, completion: nil)

}

class func saveApiToken(token: String){

    //save api token to UserDefailts

    let def = UserDefaults.standard
    def.setValue(token, forKey: "token2")
    def.synchronize()
    restartApp()
}

class func saveJobSeekerIdDefault(defaultID: String){

    //save userDefaultID to UserDefailts

    let defID = UserDefaults.standard
    defID.setValue(defaultID, forKey: "default_profile_id")
    defID.synchronize()

 restartApp()
}

class func getApiToken() -> String? {
    let def = UserDefaults.standard
    return def.object(forKey: "token2") as? String
}

class func getJobseekerID() -> String? {
    let defID = UserDefaults.standard
    return defID.object(forKey: "default_profile_id") as? String
}
}
```

After this, the initializers:

```
class UserProfileDefaults{

var userID : String
var defaultProfileType : String
var defaultProfileID : String

init?(profileDefaultsDict: [String:Any]){
    guard let userID = profileDefaultsDict["user_id"] as? String,
    let defaultProfileType = profileDefaultsDict["default_profile_type"] as? String,
    let defaultProfileID = profileDefaultsDict["default_profile_id"] as? String else {return nil}

    self.userID = userID
    self.defaultProfileID = defaultProfileID
    self.defaultProfileType = defaultProfileType
}
}
```

Then, I used Alamofire to fetch the id:

```
 class func userProfileDefault(completion: @escaping( _ error: Error?, _ userProfileDefaults: UserProfileDefaults?) -> Void){

    let url = URLs.profileDefaultsUrl

    guard let api_token = helper.getApiToken() else {
        completion(nil, nil)
        return
    }

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "Bearer \(api_token)",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    ]


    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result{
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(error, nil)
                print(error)
            case .success(let result):
                let json = JSON(result)
                print(json)

                //Data - JobSeekerDefaults
                guard let jobSeekerDefaults = json["data"].dictionaryObject else {
                    completion(nil, nil)
                    return
                }

                let userDefaultsData = UserProfileDefaults(profileDefaultsDict: jobSeekerDefaults)

                //print("Test userID01: \(userDefaultsData?.userID)")


                helper.saveJobSeekerIdDefault(defaultID: "97")

                    completion(nil, userDefaultsData)


            }
    }
}
```

I thought this was the way to get this data but I'm having nil as return. 
I really would like someone to help me because I'm stuck on this for a long time and it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look more precisely on your server response most probably you mismatch it. In `UserProfileDefaults` class initialisation set breakpoint on `guard` and print in console value of `profileDefaultsDict` like `po profileDefaultsDict`. Make sure that model you provided in initialisation in compliance with server side

Comment: Thank you. I just checked all the code and there was some things I really needed to change, such as dictionaryObject to string on the request and some minor things else. It's working good!